# Big Imageview Loaded As Small - Not Taking Full Parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm loading a big drawable, to an image view, the imageview is both wrap_content, and in the center inside a RelativeLayout.

I'm loading the drawable using Picasso library .

What to expect : Getting loaded just like the preview (in the preview it's correct ) .

What's happening : Drawable getting resized a lot, ex : it's 100, after loading it's 2, that's pretty small .

What I've tried : Getting device width/height dpi, and use them to resize the image, because i'm getting warning that the image is big (using the max as resize, or the screen height/width, i'm getting the same result ) .

Comment: I have a feeling this is because your ImageView dimensions are set to `wrap_content`. When the view is first created, your ImageView won't have any content, so its height/width is likely 0. When Picasso goes to load your image, it attempts to resize the image into the ImageView's dimensions, causing it to appear very tiny. Setting constant dimensions to your ImageView might resolve the issue.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a screenshot for the preview and what you are receiving.

Comment: Here's an example : http://i.imgur.com/4qbpkEt.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one bro.
**android scaleType = "fitXY"**

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```